# How to call .so (compiled cpp lib) from Lua

Tags: c++, lua

I want to call compiled CPP library from Lua. The compiled library is /opt/ros/indigo/lib/liborocos-kdl.so.1.3.0.

How to instantiate a class and call method of that class?

Comment: I really suggest make C wrapper around this. And then use either FFI or make Lua binding library.

Comment: @moteus: I actually have corresponding complied python lib as well. Somehow I think complied CPP lib would be easier to call. By the way, can you please explain more about writing this wrapper and further procedure in details?